# hookHeader in Prestashop, breaks flow whatever I do

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-modules

I want to add a custom js file *my_sdk.js* in my Prestashop module.

I register the hook `header` and prepare the function,
but whatever I do inside, breaks something.
My *my_sdk.js* file is correctly added by `addJS()` and it works.
The problem is that, after that, the cart is no more updated.

Whatever I write inside the `hookHeader`, it's executed but then the popup showing after the 'add to cart' action, stops working. The popup doesn't show up and the total amount of the cart is not updated until I refresh the page. It's not a problem of my js file, even if I don't import it and write something else (like an `echo`), I have the same problem.

It works only if I don't write anything (or comment everything) inside `function hookHeader()`.

```php
 public function install() {
        return (bool) $this->registerHook(['header']);
    }


    public function hookHeader($params) {
    
        $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/views/js/my_sdk.js');  // this line breaks the popup
        echo "hello, this breaks the popup"; // also just this line breaks the popup


    }
```

I really don't understand why. Tried also with hookDisplayHeader, same thing. The website works, without errors, but the cart is not updated and the popup doesn't show.

Comment: I think the issue is not in the PHP code of the hook, but in the JS file content. Have you checked your browser console for any javascript error after the file inclusion ?

Comment: yes, no error shown, and my .js works well. Is there another way to debug .js in Prestashop?

Comment: anyway, also just `echo "something"` has same result. The word is printed and visible in the header, but cart is no more updated after that.

Comment: Which version of the PrestaShop do you use? `hookHeader` is now deprecated. It would be better if you used `hookDisplayHeader`, that's the first thing. Second is that you could add your assets using `hookActionFrontControllerSetMedia`, which is supposed to be used to do just that.